# How to find the date healthkit began receiving input with Swift

Tags: swift, healthkit

I have a function that takes the step data for every day until a point, which is yet to be determined. What I need is a way to determine the day that HealthKit began receiving step count input. I tried to have it repeat until it detects 3 days of zero activity, but that seems too unspecific. Is there an object for the start date?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an object for the start date readily available, as far as I know.

One solution could be to pull all the data using a [HKStatisticsCollectionQuery](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKStatisticsCollectionQuery_Class/index.html) by day without any predicate ordered by the date, and the first date in the results should be the start date.

Hope this helps.